# Repeated mode selection

Tags: python

I wrote program which begins with mode selection and it should prompt this selection every time when one mode is completed. The code is following:

```
def get_mode():
    mode=raw_input('Welcome to Learning Helpmate BETA. Select mode, insert number of wanted mode: \n 1.mode \n 2.mode \n 3.mode\n')
    return mode

mode=get_mode()

if mode =='1':
    print 'Welcome to mode 1'
    mode=get_mode()

if mode =='2':
    print 'Welcome to mode 2'
    mode=get_mode()

if mode =='3':
    print 'Welcome to mode 3'
    mode=get_mode()
```

My problem is that when I select certain mode and run it and then try to select same mode again, my program ends and nothing will happen. How could I fix this problem without overwriting existing code too much?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you think get_mode() will bring you back to the top of your code, but it won't. You can define that mode 0 will be exit and then your code will look like this:

```
def get_mode():
    mode=raw_input('Welcome to Learning Helpmate BETA. Select mode, insert number of wanted mode: \n 1.mode \n 2.mode \n 3.mode\n')
    return mode

mode=get_mode()

while mode != '0':
    if mode =='1':
        print 'Welcome to mode 1'
        mode=get_mode()

    if mode =='2':
        print 'Welcome to mode 2'
        mode=get_mode()

    if mode =='3':
        print 'Welcome to mode 3'
        mode=get_mode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `while` loop:

```
def get_mode():
    mode=raw_input('Welcome to Learning Helpmate BETA. Select mode, insert number of wanted mode: \n 1.mode \n 2.mode \n 3.mode\n')
    return mode

while True:
    mode=get_mode()
    if mode == '1':
        print 'Welcome to mode 1'
    elif mode == '2':
        print 'Welcome to mode 2'
    elif mode == '3':
        print 'Welcome to mode 3'
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all your `if`s don't get executed again when you prompt. To fix this, use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    mode = raw_input("Enter Mode:")
    if mode == "1":
        print "Welcome to mode 1"
        do_stuff_1()
    elif mode == "2":
        print "Welcome to mode 2"
        do_stuff_2()
    etc..
```

The `while` statement executes its code block as long as its condition is true. Since the condition here is set to `True`, this will run forever, so you might want to add a abort option:

```
mode = ""
while mode != "q":
    mode = raw_input("Enter Mode: (or q to abort)")
    if mode == "1":
        do_stuff()
    etc...
```